# Segmented controls affect button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, xcode5

I need to set my segmented control to affect where my button sends a user. Yes sends them to a new screen, No sends them to the next screen.

1st Segment:

```
UISegmentedControl *par;
```

Yes (0) sends users to the UIViewController ParError on click of the next button.
No (1 - Default) sends users to the UIViewController TermsUI on click on the next button.

2nd Segment:

```
UISegmentedControl *basicOp;
```

Yes (0) sends users to the UIViewController Unsupported on click of the next button.
No (1 - Default) sends users to the UIViewController TermsUI on click of the next button.

I've tried If statement and It got to complicated, and I kept getting errors when both are selected. Anyone want a job? I can't figure it out with any of the developer guides. Help please?

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C so please explain steps of how to do things.

NOTE: I don't need this to be as subviews. What it is doing is pushing the user to another screen witch gives new instructions on what to do, and then takes them to another screen different from the original.

Comment: What should happen when you have `par segment` on `Yes(0)` and `basicOp segment` on `Yes(0)` at the same time?

Comment: I would need it to go to the unsupported screen, as even if the par is no, basicOp takes you to a screen saying that this is unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the current value selected of your SegmentControls use the property `.selectedSegmentIndex`. That will return the index of the option selected in your segmentControl [(More information about UISegmentedControl class reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html),

As I understand from your question, `par` segment has only two elements: `YES`, `NO`. On that specific order so,

```
if (par.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    // YES is selected, perform the action for going to ParError UIViewController
} else {
    // NO is selected, perform the action for going to TermsUI UIViewController
}
```

And in the case that `basicOp` has also two options on the same order : `YES`, `NO`

```
if (basicOp.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    // YES is selected, perform the action for going to Unsupported UIViewController
} else {
    // NO is selected, perform the action for going to TermsUI UIViewController
}
```

Assuming you want to achieve the following :

- If `par` is on YES (No matter what value has `basicOp`), the app sends user to `ParError UIViewController`
- If `par` is on NO and `basicOp` is on YES, the app sends user to `Unsupported UIViewController`
- If `par` is on NO and `basicOp` is on , the app sends user to `TermsUI UIViewController`

The conditionals you should have would be :

```
if (par.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    // YES is selected, perform the action for going to ParError UIViewController
} else if (basicOp.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    // YES is selected, perform the action for going to Unsupported UIViewController
} else if (par.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 || basicOp.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    // NO is selected, perform the action for going to TermsUI UIViewController
}
```

Comment: I think I understand where I went wrong with the if/else statement on my own, but what action would I call in order to have the user go to another screen on a button push?

Comment: Are you using a NavigationViewControlller ?  Then , `[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: What the app is doing is asking the user two questions, if the user says yes to the first question (par) it takes them to a one screen when the click next. If they say yes to the second (basicOp) then it takes them to the second screen. The second needs to override the first as the second takes them to an unsupported screen.

Comment: Maybe a Modal then, `[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Reread my last comment, had to change it as I don't have the rep points to post pics.

Comment: As long as I can understand your explanation, then the conditional I posted in the answer will be ok. But you don't say what kind of navigation you are using, if you are using a navigationViewController use the method for pushing a new view controller, if you are using a Modal then use that one.

Comment: Can you email me at eebean2@me.com? I'm in need of someone to help launch this app. (yes its a paid job) I'm sorry If I ask to many questions but I'm new to objective-c.